# Event when all DataGridView parameters have been loaded in designer

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `C#` `WinForms` application. I have extended the `DataGridView` to also contain a `ContextMenuStrip` component.

The `ContextMenuStrip` will be initialized depending on other parameters of the `DataGridView`, such as `AllowUserToAddRows`. Initially I tried doing this in the constructor, but the problem is that the designer loads these parameters one by one after instantiating the `DataGridView` so they are not available in the constructor.

**How can I know in my extended DataGridView when the designer has finished setting the DataGridView properties? Is there maybe an event triggered once it is done?**

Comment: [The Initialized event says just that an element has been created and its properties have all been set...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/19/loadedvsinitialized.aspx)

Comment: I'm using WinForms, not WPF so that won't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of an event, but one workaround is to add a property to the extended control named ZZInitialized like this:

```
    private bool _ZZInitialized = true;

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool ZZInitialized
    {
        get
        {
            return _ZZInitialized;
        }
        set
        {
            _ZZInitialized = value;
            //Do what you need to do after all other properties are set.
        }
    }
```

When all the other properties that occur alphabetically before are called, the designer code calls this one and I can execute my own code.

Note that events are added after this in the designer code.